# Returning zipcodes for longitude/latitude with geopy - avoiding GeocoderTimedOut: ('Service timed out', 'occurred at index ...')

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

This question is not new and was discussed multiple times, but I am new to Python.

[Geopy too slow - timeout all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506272/geopy-too-slow-timeout-all-the-time)

[Timeout error in Python geopy geocoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218394/timeout-error-in-python-geopy-geocoder)

I have a dataset of 11000 geolocations and would like to have their zipcodes.

My data looks like:

```
   Longitude   Latitude
0 -87.548627  41.728184
1 -87.737227  41.749111
2 -87.743974  41.924143
3 -87.659294  41.869314
4 -87.727808  41.877007
```

Using this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352961/convert-lat-lon-to-zip-postal-code-using-python), I wrote a function, which works for the first 10-20 rows, but gives a timeout error.

```
# Create a function for zip codes extraction
def get_zipcode(df, geolocator, lat_field, lon_field):
   location = geolocator.reverse((df[lat_field], df[lon_field]))
   return location.raw['address']['postcode']

geolocator = geopy.Nominatim(user_agent = 'my-application')

# Test a sample with 20 rows
test = bus_stops_geo.head(20)

# Extract zip codes for the sample
zipcodes = test.apply(get_zipcode, axis = 1, geolocator = geolocator, 
                           lat_field = 'Latitude', lon_field = 'Longitude')

print(zipcodes)

0     60617
1     60652
2     60639
3     60607
4     60644
5     60659
6     60620
7     60626
8     60610
9     60660
10    60625
11    60645
12    60628
13    60620
14    60629
15    60628
16    60644
17    60638
18    60657
19    60631
dtype: object
```

I tried to change the timeout time, but failed so far.

My questions:

- How to achieve this for 11000 rows?
- How to rewrite this function and return not only zips, but initial long and lat too?
- Any simple alternative solutions in programming languages like R or using proprietary software (**paid options work for me**)?

Tremendously appreciate any help!

Comment: Possible solution with [tag:R]: [*How to batch reverse geocode in R?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42337619/2204410)

Comment: @Jaap, worked! Kudos!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to batch reverse geocode in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337619/how-to-batch-reverse-geocode-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of geopy with pandas is described in docs: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.22.0/#usage-with-pandas

Solution with geopy:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame([
   ...:     [-87.548627, 41.728184],
   ...:     [-87.737227, 41.749111],
   ...:     [-87.743974, 41.924143],
   ...:     [-87.659294, 41.869314],
   ...:     [-87.727808, 41.877007],
   ...: ], columns=["Longitude", "Latitude"])

In [2]: from tqdm import tqdm
   ...: tqdm.pandas()
   ...:
   ...: from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
   ...: geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
   ...:
   ...: from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
   ...: reverse = RateLimiter(geolocator.reverse, min_delay_seconds=1)

In [3]: df['Location'] = df.progress_apply(
   ...:     lambda row: reverse((row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])),
   ...:     axis=1
   ...: )
100%|█████████████████████████████| 5/5 [00:06<00:00,  1.24s/it]

In [4]: def parse_zipcode(location):
   ...:     if location and location.raw.get('address') and location.raw['address'].get('postcode'):
   ...:         return location.raw['address']['postcode']
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return None
   ...: df['Zipcode'] = df['Location'].apply(parse_zipcode)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   Longitude   Latitude                                           Location Zipcode
0 -87.548627  41.728184  (Olive Harvey College South Chicago Learning C...   60617
1 -87.737227  41.749111  (7900, South Kilpatrick Avenue, Chicago, Cook ...   60652
2 -87.743974  41.924143  (4701, West Fullerton Avenue, Beat 2522, Belmo...   60639
3 -87.659294  41.869314  (1301-1307, West Taylor Street, Near West Side...   60607
4 -87.727808  41.877007  (4053, West Jackson Boulevard, West Garfield P...   60644
```

If paid options work for you, consider using any other geocoding service than the free Nominatim, such as MapQuest or PickPoint.

Comment: Kostya, what is the limit of your solution? In terms of returned zip codes? Paid works if there is a good guideline on how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Nominatim has a limit on rate (1 request per second), see https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/ . MapQuest and PickPoint limit by number of queries, see https://developer.mapquest.com/plans and https://pickpoint.io/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Python solution and a different approach with shapefiles, but for benefits of the SO community I will post an answer with R (a tip from @Jaap and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337619/how-to-batch-reverse-geocode-in-r)).

First, you need the [US zipcodes shapefile](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2015-cartographic-boundary-file-5-digit-zip-code-tabulation-area-for-united-states-1-500000/resource/c5d6eaae-39fe-4470-8a75-6a9777f63ede) (for US location).

```
# Install packages
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)

# Import zips shapefile and transform CRS 
zips <- readOGR("cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.shp")
zips <- spTransform(zips, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

# Read bus stops data
bus_stops <- read_csv("CTA_BusStops.csv")

# A tibble: 6 x 14
SYSTEMSTOP OBJECTID the_geom                            STREET     CROSS_ST          
DIR   POS   ROUTESSTPG OWLROUTES CITY   STATUS PUBLIC_NAM          POINT_X POINT_Y
   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>                               <chr>      <chr>             
<chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>   <dbl>
1      11953      193 POINT (-87.54862703700002 41.72818~ 92ND STRE~ BALTIMORE         
EB    NS    95         NA        CHICA~      1 92nd Street & Balt~   -87.5    41.7
2       2723      194 POINT (-87.737227163 41.7491110710~ 79TH STRE~ KILPATRICK (east~ 
EB    NS    79         NA        CHICA~      1 79th Street & Kilp~   -87.7    41.7
3       1307      195 POINT (-87.74397362600001 41.92414~ FULLERTON  KILPATRICK        
EB    NS    74         NA        CHICA~      1 Fullerton & Kilpat~   -87.7    41.9
4       6696      196 POINT (-87.65929365400001 41.86931~ TAYLOR     THROOP            
EB    NS    157        NA        CHICA~      1 Taylor & Throop       -87.7    41.9
5         22      197 POINT (-87.72780787099998 41.87700~ JACKSON    KARLOV            
EB    FS    126        NA        CHICA~      1 Jackson & Karlov      -87.7    41.9
6       4767      198 POINT (-87.71978000000001 41.97552~ FOSTER     MONTICELLO        
EB    NS    92         NA        CHICA~      1 Foster & Monticello   -87.7    42.0

# Rename two columns for long and lat
bus_stops <- rename(bus_stops, longitude = POINT_X, latitude = POINT_Y)

# Extract long and lat columns only
test_bus_stops <- bus_stops[ , c(13, 14)]

# Transform coordinates into a SpatialPointsDataFrame
bus_stops_spatial <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = test_bus_stops, data = bus_stops, 
proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
class(bus_stops_spatial) # [1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"

# Subset only the zipcodes in which points are found
zips_subset <- zips[bus_stops_spatial, ]

# NOTE: the column in zips_subset containing zipcodes is ZCTA5CE10
# Use over() to overlay points in polygons and then add that to the original dataframe
# Create a separate column
bus_stops_zip <- over(bus_stops_spatial, zips_subset[, "ZCTA5CE10"]) 
bus_stops_zip
```

I double-checked results long and lat via [this link](https://www.melissa.com/v2/lookups/latlngzip4/) randomly. It matches.

```
# Merge bus stops with bus stop zips
bus_stops <- cbind(bus_stops, bus_stops_zip)

# Rename zip_code column
bus_stops <- rename(bus_stops, zip_code = ZCTA5CE10)
head(bus_stops)

# Display zip
head(bus_stops[, 13:15])
longitude latitude zip_code
1 -87.54863 41.72818    60617
2 -87.73723 41.74911    60652
3 -87.74397 41.92414    60639
4 -87.65929 41.86931    60607
5 -87.72781 41.87701    60624
6 -87.71978 41.97553    60625

# Extract as csv
write.csv(bus_stops,'bus_stops_zips.csv')
```